# Global Coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, scoping

How can I declare coordinates in a block and access them from outside of the block?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x / \y in {
    1 /  3,
    2 /  8,
    3 / 14,
  }{
    \coordinate (N\x) at (\x,\y);
    \path[draw] (N\x) circle (1em);      %% ok
  };
  \path[draw] (N1) -- (N3);              %% not ok
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: One thing to note about the answers you've gotten: they've removed the last comma.  Your loop executes *four* times; the last with `\x` and `\y` empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the spaces between your coordinates. i.e.

```
\foreach \x / \y in {1/3,2/8,3/14}
```

or

```
\foreach \x / \y in {
   1/3,
   2/8,
   3/14%
}
```

should work.

**NOTE**

As Andrew pointed out, the `%` is necessary in the second code block to avoid additional spaces etc. getting appended to the intended `14`. This is not necessary in the first code block as the `14` is followed immediately by a `}`. The first code block is probably the best way to do this for short lists.

The original code from the question uses a comma where the `%` is in the second block above, which causes the `foreach` to do an additional unwanted loop iteration with no content. This results in the creation of a coordinate called `N` at `(1,1)`, which is neither wanted nor desirable.

Answer (score 6):

As it is written in others answers, it's not a problem of `global coordinates`but a problem with wrong names of coordinates because blank are dangerous in the arguments of `\foreach`

In this special case, would be more concise : ( but in the general case, the line     `\coordinate (N\x) at (\x,\y);`can be avoided)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \y [count=\x from 1] in {3,8,14}
      \draw   (\x,\y) coordinate (N\x) circle (1em);
  \draw   (N1) -- (N3); 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this without modification. The problem is that your coordinates are not named `N1`, `N2`, and `N3` due to spurious spaces. Change it to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x / \y in {1/3,2/8,3/14%
  }{
    \coordinate (N\x) at (\x,\y);
    \path[draw] (N\x) circle (1em);      %% ok
  };
  \path[draw] (N1) -- (N3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and you are fine.

As Andrew already mentioned as a comment to your question. The last `,` has to go. It runs through the loop again with `\x` and `\y` empty. This does actually draw an extra circle at `(1,1)` and defines the coordinate `N`. I am not completely sure why it gets drawn at `(1,1)` to be honest. I would expect it to default to `(0,0)` instead. Does anybody have an explanation for this?

**Edit:** I think I know why it occurs at `(1,1)`. The coordinate system has a value for `x` and `y` and when you say something like `(3,7)` this means take `3` steps of size `x` in the `x` direction and `7` steps of size `y` in the `y` direction. This allows to write coordinates without units and change the 'scale' afterwards. These values for `x` and `y` default to `1 cm` and not `0 cm` such that writing `(3,7)` becomes `(3 cm, 7 cm)` instead of `(0 cm, 0 cm)` which would be far less usefull. When you leave them empty, the defaults for `x` and `y` are used.

Comment: Since this is all about spaces, it would be good to also remove the space after the `14` caused by the new line.  Although in this case it makes no difference, in other cases it might.  A `%` is probably simplest as it keeps the layout.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: good suggestion. I added the `%` to not interfere with the formatting.

Comment: @wh1t3 you need to add \end{tikzpicture} at the end of your code

Comment: @Altermundus: thanks, must have not copied the entire thing by mistake `:-)`

Comment: I got curious.  At some point, the coordinate calculation calls `\pgf@x = \pgftemp@x \pgf@xx`.  In this, `\pgf@x` is to be the `x` coordinate of the point.  `\pgf@xx` is the "unit" of the current `x` vector (~28pt by default).  Then `\pgftemp@x` is the result of sending the *specified* `x` coordinate through `\pgfmathparse`.  In this case, that returns nothing, by which I mean an *empty* token, not a *zero* token.  Thus the line reads `\pgf@x = \pgf@xx` and so `\pgf@x` ends up as `~28pt`, or `1cm`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Am I then correct in assuming that when you specify a coordinate like `(3 mm, 2 mm)` the macro `\pgftemp@x` expands to `3` and `\pgf@xx` expands to `1 mm` instead? Or is this handled some other way? It would seem that the "unit vector" would need to be changed in that case (or `\pgftemp@x` scaled somehow).

Comment: There are different branches for things like `3mm` and things like `3`.  There's a check for whether units are specified.  The empty token doesn't have units so it goes down the "no units" branch which is where this code is executed.  The code I quoted takes place once the branch has been chosen.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I see, I could have guessed from the manual. It states there that when dimensionless arguments are given the `xyz` coordinate system is used instead of the regular `xy/canvas` cs as well. It is also interesting to note that the "unit vector" is not required to be strictly horizontal. That is, the `x`-vector is allowed to have values other than `0` as its `y` and `z` components, while the `x` component may be anything, including `0`. This is directly the reason that `(3cm, 2)` is interpreted as `(3cm, 2pt)`.